# Is it impossible to write a functioning tmux shell script that launches 3 panes of ncmpcpp?

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

This is the second time I'm posting the question, because this entire situation ended up being more confusing than I thought.

I'm trying to make a script that opens tmux, splits it into 3 panes, makes them equally sized horizontally, and launches ncmpcpp in all of them. This is the script I managed to write:

```
#!/bin/sh

tmux new-session -d 'ncmpcpp'
printf 'creating session\n'
tmux split-window -h 'ncmpcpp'
printf 'window split 1\n'
tmux split-window -h 'ncmpcpp'
printf 'window split 2\n'
tmux select-layout even-horizontal
printf 'evening out panes\n'
tmux a #
printf 'attaching session\n'
```

I'm a beginner in writing scripts at all, so sorry if the mistake here is obvious. The printfs are there so that I could identify where exactly the script crashes tmux. Apparently, it crashes at `tmux a #`.

The weird thing is that, the crash happens instantly. I can't take a screenshot due to just how rapidly it disappears.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of `std::logic_error
what() : constructed window couldn't fit into terminal'
```

Basically, the panes are too small for ncmpcpp to launch in. Even though I could manually launch ncmpcpp in way smaller terminals.

However, after some messing around, I accidentally "kind of" solved the problem.

I screwed around with the script, and I ended up with this:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf '\033[8;29;252t'
tmux new-session -d 

tmux select-layout even-horizontal
tmux send-keys -t 0 'tput cols' Enter
tmux split-window -h 

sleep 1

tmux select-layout even-horizontal
tmux send-keys -t 1 'tput cols' Enter
tmux split-window -h 

sleep 1

tmux select-layout even-horizontal
tmux send-keys -t 2 'tput cols' Enter

sleep 1

tmux send-keys -t 0 'ncmpcpp' Enter
tmux send-keys -t 1 'ncmpcpp' Enter
tmux send-keys -t 2 'ncmpcpp' Enter
tmux a #
```

It takes a 3 second pause at the beginning, before immediately launching tmux, with 3 panes, all of them having ncmpcpp on them.

...*Sometimes.*

It doesn't work all the time, sometimes certain panes just crash outright, sometimes they don't.

I'm honestly really confused as to what's going on here. My guess is the size of the panes isn't recorded well, enough to screw up the value of how many columns/rows each pane has. But I'm honestly stumped.

That's why I'm asking this - ncmpcpp only launches when the size of the terminal is big enough. Since tmux messes with the actual values saying what the columns are, is it impossible to do the things I said in the title?

Comment: Have a look at the tool tmuxp (https://tmuxp.git-pull.com/en/latest/). You just create a yaml file which describes how many windows with what panes you want to create and what programs you want to start in them. Its a much easier the writing a skriptfile.

Comment: I would rather try and write a script for now, especially since I have no idea how to type YAML commands etc.

Comment: Yaml is just a text file. Have a look at the link form above. There is an example.

Comment: Didn't particularly work well. Same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought it was impossible, but there was something I missed.

`tmux new-session -d`

In order for ncmpcpp to work, the size of the actual session needed to be specified. This is what was messing with the values. To fix it, I did this:

`tmux new-session -d -x 252 -y 29`

It worked well after that.

Here's the final script:

```
 #!/bin/sh

printf '\033[8;29;252t'
tmux new-session -d -x 252 -y 29

tmux select-layout even-horizontal
tmux split-window -h 

tmux select-layout even-horizontal
tmux split-window -h 

tmux select-layout even-horizontal

tmux send-keys -t 0 'ncmpcpp' Enter
tmux send-keys -t 1 'ncmpcpp' Enter
tmux send-keys -t 2 'ncmpcpp' Enter

tmux send-keys -t 1 '='
tmux send-keys -t 2 '8'

tmux a #
```

Answer (score 3):

So

```
#!/bin/sh

printf '\033[8;29;252t'
tmux new-session -d -x 252 -y 29

tmux select-layout even-horizontal
tmux send-keys -t 0 'tput cols' Enter
tmux split-window -h 

sleep 1

tmux select-layout even-horizontal
tmux send-keys -t 1 'tput cols' Enter
tmux split-window -h 

sleep 1

tmux select-layout even-horizontal
tmux send-keys -t 2 'tput cols' Enter

sleep 1

tmux send-keys -t 0 'ncmpcpp -s playlist' Enter
tmux send-keys -t 1 'ncmpcpp -s media_library' Enter
tmux send-keys -t 2 'ncmpcpp -s clock' Enter

# help,playlist,browser,search_engine,media_library,
# playlist_editor,tag_editor,outputs,visualizer,clock

tmux a #
```

is your own answer. Have you tried altering the ncmpcpp layout:
(called with -c)

`ncmpcpp -c ~/.my_ncmpcpp.conf`

```
#~/.my_ncmpcpp.conf
#edited from https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1236890#p1236890
song_list_format = "{$5%a $9}{$2%t$9}|{$7%f$9}$7$R{%b }{$3%4l$9}$9
song_status_format = "{{%a{ \"%b\"{ (%y)}} - }{%t}}|{%f}"
song_library_format = "{%N - }{%t}|{%f}"
now_playing_prefix = "$b"
alternative_header_first_line_format = "$b$8$aqqu$/a$9 $2{%t}|{%f}$9 $8$atqq$/a$9$/b"
alternative_header_second_line_format = "$b$8$aqqu$/a$9 $3{%b}|{%f}$9 $8$atqq$/a$9$/b"
song_columns_list_format = "(4)[blue]{n:#} (25)[blue]{a} (40)[blue]{t|f} (30)[blue]{b} (7f)[blue]    {l}"
playlist_show_remaining_time = "yes"
playlist_separate_albums = "yes"
playlist_display_mode = "columns" (classic/columns)
browser_display_mode = "columns" (classic/columns)
search_engine_display_mode = "columns" (classic/columns)
progressbar_look = "✠❱•"
default_place_to_search_in = "database"
user_interface = "alternative"
header_visibility = "no"
titles_visibility = "yes"
show_hidden_files_in_local_browser = "no"
screen_switcher_mode = "browser, search_engine"
startup_screen = "search_engine"
ask_before_clearing_playlists =  "yes"
clock_display_seconds = "yes"
display_volume_level = "yes"
display_bitrate = "no"
display_remaining_time = "yes"
regular_expressions = "extended"
ignore_leading_the = "yes"
mouse_support = "no"
enable_window_title = "yes"
allow_for_physical_item_deletion = "no"
external_editor = "vim"
use_console_editor = "yes"
colors_enabled = "yes"
header_window_color = "default"
main_window_color = "white"
progressbar_color = "green"
alternative_ui_separator_color = "red"
active_column_color = "red"
```

or maybe this is something that could get you what you are after.

```
#!/bin/bash
SESSION=ncmpcpp
#url=https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1167179#p1167179
tmux -2 has-session -t $SESSION
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    tmux -2 attach -t $SESSION
    exit 0;
fi

tmux -2 new-session -d -s $SESSION 'ncmpcpp -s playlist'

for i in "C-l" "Enter" "2"
    do tmux -2 send-keys -t $SESSION:0.0 "$i"
done

tmux -2 set -t $SESSION -g status off

tmux -2 attach-session -t $SESSION
```

Comment: I'd need to familiarize myself more with tmux-scripts to understand what's happening in the second codeblock. However, I don't get how that config could particularly help with the problem - which happened to be caused with some crazy resizing issues with tmux. Also, I removed the excess commands such as sleep, tput cols, etc.!